# xslt wrapping duplicate lines case insensitive inside a for-each

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to write a loop using XSLT so that it automatically groups all items with the same ID but in a case insensitive way. Unfortunately the data that I am trying to parse through is client driven so I cannot change it prior to load. 
regardless here is a XML structure...

```
<Document>
    <Row>
        <Cell>ID</Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell>hi</Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell>Hi</Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell>Hello</Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell>Hello</Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell>Hola</Cell>
    </Row>
</Document>
```

This is the XSLT I am currently using...

```
  <xsl:template match="Document">
    <NewDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <xsl:for-each select="//Row[position() &gt; 1]/Cell[1][not(.=preceding::Row/Cell[1])]">
        <xsl:variable name="currentOrderID" select="." />
        <xsl:variable name="currentOrderGroup" select="//Row[Cell[1] = $currentOrderID]" />

        <MainID>
          <xsl:value-of select="$currentOrderGroup[1]/Cell[1]"/>
        </MainID>
        <IDs>
          <xsl:for-each select="$currentOrderGroup">
            <id>
              <xsl:value-of select="Cell[1]"/>
            </id>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </IDs>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </NewDocument>
  </xsl:template>
```

This is just wrapping up things as expected in a CaSe SeNSiTiVe way... 
I've been trying to use a translate in there in order to make everything uppercase, however I can't seem to get the syntax just right.

The result I am trying to achieve here is this:

```
<NewDocument>
  <MainID>hi</MainID>
  <IDs>
    <id>hi</id>
    <id>Hi</id>
  </IDs>  
  <MainID>Hello</MainID>
  <IDs>
    <id>Hello</id>
    <id>Hello</id>
  </IDs>
  <MainID>Hola</MainID>
  <IDs>
    <id>Hola</id>
  </IDs>
</NewDocument>
```

Can't seem to find anything specifically for what I need. 
Thanks!

Comment: Seems like <xsl:sort> would be your friend here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT1.0, to convert strings to lower case you need to use the rather cumbersome **translate** function in xpath.

```
translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

Furthermore, your problem is one of grouping, and in XSLT1.0 that usually means a technique known as Meunchian Grouping. To do, this you first define a key to look up items in the groups you require

```
<xsl:key 
   name="Cell" 
   match="Cell" 
   use="translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"/>
```

Here we are looking up cells based on their (lower-case) text content.

To find the first element in each group, you look for **Cell** elements in the XML which also happen to be the first element occurring in your look-up key

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="Row/Cell
   [generate-id() 
    = generate-id(
       key('Cell', 
         translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))[1])]"/>
```

Then, when you match the first element, you can then match all elements within the group by looking at the key.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:key name="Cell" match="Cell" use="translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"/>

   <xsl:template match="Document">
      <NewDocument>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Row/Cell[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Cell', translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))[1])]"/>
      </NewDocument>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Cell">
      <MainID>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </MainID>
      <IDs>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('Cell', translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))" mode="group"/>
      </IDs>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Cell" mode="group">
      <id>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </id>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of the **mode** attribute, to distinguish between the two templates matching **Cell** elements.

When applied to your XML, the following is output:

```
<NewDocument>
   <MainID>ID</MainID>
   <IDs>
      <id>ID</id>
   </IDs>
   <MainID>hi</MainID>
   <IDs>
      <id>hi</id>
      <id>Hi</id>
   </IDs>
   <MainID>Hello</MainID>
   <IDs>
      <id>Hello</id>
      <id>Hello</id>
   </IDs>
   <MainID>Hola</MainID>
   <IDs>
      <id>Hola</id>
   </IDs>
</NewDocument>
```

Note, I wasn't sure what to do with the Cell with **ID** as a value, so I left that it in. If you do want to exclude it, just add this line to the XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="Cell[. = 'ID']" />
```

Comment: Also, I just wanted to skip the first row as it has data that is not relevant to the load. so in doing that I just changed the main call to `<xsl:apply-templates select="Row[position() &gt; 1]/Cell[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Cell', translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))[1])]"/>` and it works like a champ.